# Is it possible to delete all "data-curves" which are outside from my diagram? (only the overlapping part)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is it possible to cut/delete all "data-curves" which are outside from my diagram? (Lines which are overlapping) The caption "ND" and "Formel" should be allowed to be outside.

The command `restrict x to domain=1000:10000000,` does not work.
See also my screenshot. thank you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}
    [
        no marks,  % Keine Punktmarkierungen der Datenpunkte (nur Linie plotten)
        enlarge x limits=false,    % x-Achse wird logarithmisch
        title={Spannungskollektiv bei R=-1, $\sigma_{x}$},    % Titel
        width=8cm,     % Breite Diagramm
%        height=7cm,   % Höhe Diagramm
%        scale only axis=false  % Skalierung auf Basis inkl. Achsenbeschriftungen
        grid=major,          % none / minor / major
        xmin=10000, xmax=100000000,  % x: Darstellungsbereich
        ymin=0, ymax=200,  % y: Darstellungsbereich
        xlabel={Lastzyklen N},   % x: Label
        ylabel={Amplitude $\sigma_{a,x}$},   % y: Label
%        extra y ticks  = {110},   % Zusätzliche Markierungen auf der y-Achse
%        extra y tick labels  = {}, %Beschriftung Zusatz-ticks ausblenden
        samples=50,  % Auflösung der Funktionen
        restrict y to domain=0:200,
        %restrict x to domain=10000:100000000,
        clip=false
     ]

\addplot+[const plot mark right,thin,blue] table[x=colcount,y=colamplitude] {
colamplitude    colcount
142.387 1
142.387 50054
111.692 250266
107.619 300319
107.221 350372
105.793 550584
103.462 600637
98.2452 800849
};
\addplot+[red,thick,mark=none,domain=10000:1000000] {143.295225788333*(1000000/x)^(1/5)};
\addplot+[red,thin,dashed,mark=none,domain=1000000:1000000000] {143.295225788333*(1000000/x)^(1/5)};
\addplot+[red,thick,mark=none,domain=1000000:1000000000] {143.295225788333};
\node[red,left] at (axis cs:1000000,143.295225788333) {\footnotesize $ 143.3 $};

\draw[yellow!30!orange,thick] ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,15.8946951655}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,15.8946951655});
\draw[green!70!red,thick,dashed] ({axis cs:1000000,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1}) -- ({axis cs:1000000,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0});
\draw [green!70!red,very thick,restrict y to domain=0:200,](axis cs:0,110.1354266585) -- (axis cs:1000000,110.1354266585);  % Horizontale Linie
\draw [green!70!red,very thick](axis cs:1000000,0) -- (axis cs:1000000,110.1354266585);  % Vertikale Linie
\node[green!70!red,right] at (axis cs:1000000,110.1354266585) {\footnotesize $ \sigma_{\ddot{a}qu} = 110.1 $};
\node[blue,above right] at (axis cs:10000,142.387) {\footnotesize $ \sigma_{a,1} = 142.4 $};

\draw[green!60!red,ultra thick] ({axis cs:50000000,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1}) --
({axis cs:50000000,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0});

\draw[blue,thick] ({axis cs:60000000,30}) -- ({axis cs:600000000,100}) node[above,right] {Formel 2};

\draw[black!60!red,ultra thick] ({axis cs:1e6,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1}) --
  ({axis cs:1e6,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,-0.3}) node [below] {$ND$}; 
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Change `clip=false` to `clip=true`.

Comment: yes i understand but then my caption is deleted ("ND" and "Formel")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clipping is the best option, so set `clip=true`, but of course you would also clip your labels. Solution for that is to define the coordinates of your labels inside the axis, but do the drawing outside:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}
    [
        no marks,  % Keine Punktmarkierungen der Datenpunkte (nur Linie plotten)
        enlarge x limits=false,    % x-Achse wird logarithmisch
        title={Spannungskollektiv bei R=-1, $\sigma_{x}$},    % Titel
        width=8cm,     % Breite Diagramm
%        height=7cm,   % Höhe Diagramm
%        scale only axis=false  % Skalierung auf Basis inkl. Achsenbeschriftungen
        grid=major,          % none / minor / major
        xmin=10000, xmax=100000000,  % x: Darstellungsbereich
        ymin=0, ymax=200,  % y: Darstellungsbereich
        xlabel={Lastzyklen N},   % x: Label
        xlabel style={xshift = 2cm},
        ylabel={Amplitude $\sigma_{a,x}$},   % y: Label
%        extra y ticks  = {110},   % Zusätzliche Markierungen auf der y-Achse
%        extra y tick labels  = {}, %Beschriftung Zusatz-ticks ausblenden
        samples=50,  % Auflösung der Funktionen
        restrict y to domain=0:200,
        %restrict x to domain=10000:100000000,
        clip=true
     ]

\addplot+[const plot mark right,thin,blue] table[x=colcount,y=colamplitude] {
colamplitude    colcount
142.387 1
142.387 50054
111.692 250266
107.619 300319
107.221 350372
105.793 550584
103.462 600637
98.2452 800849
};
\addplot+[red,thick,mark=none,domain=10000:1000000] {143.295225788333*(1000000/x)^(1/5)};
\addplot+[red,thin,dashed,mark=none,domain=1000000:1000000000] {143.295225788333*(1000000/x)^(1/5)};
\addplot+[red,thick,mark=none,domain=1000000:1000000000] {143.295225788333};
\node[red,left] at (axis cs:1000000,143.295225788333) {\footnotesize $ 143.3 $};

\draw[yellow!30!orange,thick] ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,15.8946951655}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,15.8946951655});
\draw[green!70!red,thick,dashed] ({axis cs:1000000,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1}) -- ({axis cs:1000000,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0});
\draw [green!70!red,very thick](axis cs:0,110.1354266585) -- (axis cs:1000000,110.1354266585);  % Horizontale Linie
\draw [green!70!red,very thick](axis cs:1000000,0) -- (axis cs:1000000,110.1354266585);  % Vertikale Linie
\node[green!70!red,right] at (axis cs:1000000,110.1354266585) {\footnotesize $ \sigma_{\ddot{a}qu} = 110.1 $};
\node[blue,above right] at (axis cs:10000,142.387) {\footnotesize $ \sigma_{a,1} = 142.4 $};

\draw[green!60!red,ultra thick] ({axis cs:50000000,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1}) --
({axis cs:50000000,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0});

\coordinate (Fa) at ({axis cs:60000000,30});
\coordinate (Fb) at ({axis cs:600000000,100});
\coordinate (NDa) at ({axis cs:1e6,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
\coordinate (NDb) at ({axis cs:1e6,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,-0.3});

\end{semilogxaxis}

\draw[black!60!red,ultra thick] (NDa) -- node [pos=1,below] {$N\!D$} (NDb);
\draw[blue,thick] (Fa) -- (Fb) node[above,right] {Formel 2};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the ND-label you should either use `-- node [pos=1,below] ...` or `-- (NDb) node [below] ...` to get the correct positioning. As of now it is placed midway on the path. And off-topic: I guess *ND* is supposed to be a two letter variable name, if so it should be typeset with `$\mathit{ND}$` to get the correct spacing. `$ND$` will be interpreted as the product of *N* and *D*, and will give a little space between them (*N* *D* ).

Comment: @hooy I just used the OP's code as it was. But of course, one could further improve it.

Comment: I am aware, which is why I specified "off-topic", I just noticed it while correcting the placement of the node :-) Oh, and +1 for your answer of course!

Answer (score 5):

thewaywewalk presented in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344704/95441) the way of using `clip=false` (which is the default in PGFPlots) and moving the stuff "outside" of the axis region outside the `semilogxaxis` environment. This *can* be done, but has the downside that you cannot use the axis coordinates (e.g. `axis cs:`) any more to place stuff, expect using the workaround of defining `\coordinate`s first which then are referred to in the surrounding `tikzpicture` environment.

Another possibility is to use `clip mode=individual` which does only clip stuff of the `\addplot` commands away. This I have used here, so there is no need to "draw" anything directly in the `tikzpicture`/outside the `semilogxaxis` environment.

Besides that main point I noticed that you do a lot of stuff in a "very complicated way". So I reorganized a lot of your original code the get almost the same result in a much "cleaner" (not necessarily simpler) way.

For more details have a look at the comments in the code

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    % <-- added to be able to plot the "ä"
\usepackage{amsmath}           % <-- added to have the `\text' command
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.11,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        /tikz/declare function={
            % moved definitions of axis limits here for later use
            % (also changed to scientific format which is much simpler to check)
            xmin=1e4;
            xmax=1e8;
            ymin=0;
            ymax=200;
            % also declare some other "reused" values here as variables
            % (please rename them to something more useful)
            Blue=142.387;
            Red=143.295225788333;
            Yellow=15.8946951655;
            Green=110.1354266585;
        },
        % create a style for the (value) labels
        Node/.style={
            font=\footnotesize,
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                % show numbers with one digit after the decimal separator
                precision=1,
                % and use a comma as decimal separator
                use comma,
        },
    ]
        \begin{semilogxaxis}[
            width=8cm,
            % used above declared variables for the axis limits
            xmin=xmin,
            xmax=xmax,
            ymin=ymin,
            ymax=ymax,
            xlabel={Anzahl Lastzyklen $N$},
            ylabel={Amplitude $\sigma_{a,x}$},
            enlarge x limits=false,
            grid=major,
            title={Spannungskollektiv bei $R = -1$, $\sigma_{x}$},
            % move title a bit up, so the (new) "ND" label has enough room
            title style={
                yshift=1ex,
            },
%            % this is a `tikz' option ...
%            no marks,
            % this is the `pgfplots' option
            % (and with that you don't have to write "mark=none" at every `\addplot'
            no markers,
            samples=50,
            % =================================================================
            % these are not needed any more when you use the newly added option
%            restrict y to domain=0:200,
%            clip=false,
            clip mode=individual,
            % =================================================================
        ]

        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % addplots
            \addplot+ [
                const plot mark right,
                thin,
                blue,
            ] table [x=colcount,y=colamplitude] {
                colamplitude    colcount
                142.387 1
                142.387 50054
                111.692 250266
                107.619 300319
                107.221 350372
                105.793 550584
                103.462 600637
                98.2452 800849
            };
            \addplot+ [
                red,
                thick,
                domain=1e4:1e6,
            ] {Red*(1000000/x)^(1/5)};
            \addplot+ [
                red,
                thin,
                dashed,
                domain=1e6:1e8,
            ] {Red*(1000000/x)^(1/5)};
            \addplot+ [
                red,
                thick,
                mark=none,
                domain=1e6:1e8,
            ] {Red}
                % use the `Node' style here
                node [pos=0,left,font=\footnotesize]
                    % also don't state the number itself again and again.
                    % Declare it as a variable and then use this instead.
                    % Then you need to change only *one* point to adapt the
                    % lines position as well as the corresponding label
                    {\pgfmathparse{Red}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}
            ;

        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % lines + labels
            \draw [yellow!30!orange,thick]
%            % way to complicated ...
%                ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,15.8946951655})
%                    -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,15.8946951655});
            % ... much simpler is
                (xmin,Yellow) -- (xmax,Yellow);

            \node [blue,above right,Node] at (xmin,Blue)
                {$\sigma_{a,1} = \pgfmathparse{Blue}
                    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$};

            \draw [green!70!red,thick,dashed] (1e6,ymin) -- (1e6,ymax);
            % horizontal + vertical line
            \draw [
                green!70!red,
                very thick,
                % this should have caused an error, because you are trying to
                % use a PGFPlots option in a TikZ command
                % (which isn't very useful)
%                restrict y to domain=0:200,
            ]   (xmin,Green) -- (1e6,Green) -- (1e6,ymin)
                node [pos=0,right,Node]
                    {$\sigma_{\text{äqu}} = \pgfmathparse{Green}
                        \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$}
            ;

            \draw [green!60!red,ultra thick] (5e7,ymin) -- (5e7,ymax);

            % I moved the label above the plot, where it doesn't cross the
            % tick label and the axis label
            \draw [black!60!red,ultra thick]
                (1e6,ymin) -- (1e6,ymax)
                        node [above,font=\footnotesize] {$\mathit{ND}$};

%            % again this is a very complicated way to state this ...
%            \draw [blue,thick]
%                ({axis cs:60000000,30}) -- ({axis cs:600000000,100})
%                    node [above,right] {Formel 2};
            % ... how about
            \node [
                coordinate,
                pin={
                    [%
                        pin edge={
                            blue,
                            thin,
                        },
                        blue,
%                        % if you want the pin a bit longer
%                        pin distance=10ex,
                    ]above right:Formel 2%
                },
            ] at (6e7,30) {};

        \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Didn't know about the individual clipping mode, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @thewaywewalk, you are welcome. I also learn a lot by looking at the answers of others. PGFPlots has *way* to much possibilities to remember all of them ;)