# Caption outside of a diagram. How?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams

Nearly the same question like:
[Is it possible to delete all "data-curves" which are outside from my diagram? (only the overlapping part)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344699/is-it-possible-to-delete-all-data-curves-which-are-outside-from-my-diagram-o)

But in this case i have a 3D diagram with the view from top (2D view). I want to do a caption like in this picture -> [image]

The commands the guys told (in the past) me does not work in this 3D plot. See the link to the other question.

My Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=8cm,    
xmin=18.18,  
xmax=90.18,   
ymin=0,  
ymax=36,   
enlargelimits=0.01,   
xmajorgrids, 
ymajorgrids,  
colorbar sampled,  
only marks,  
view={0}{90}, % view the plot from the top
set layers=standard,  
mark layer=axis background, 
]
\addplot3[scatter,  
mark=diamond*,      
point meta=\thisrow{count},  
]
table {
mean    Amplitude   count
54.18   27.54   50053
58.68   25.2    50053
64.98   15.66   50053
57.24   0.72    12112800
};  
\draw[yellow!30!orange,thick](axis cs:14.8865784499055,4.96219281663516,0) -- (axis cs:169.38,4.96219281663516,0);  % Cut-off-Linie
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `xmin` and `xmax` values directly using `\pgfkeysvalueof`, this saves you the problem of clipping or not. But the annotation itself is just as well drawn outside the `axis` environment.

I defined a coordinate on the cut off line to help get the position right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} % with 1.11 or higher you don't need axis cs: in coordinates
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=8cm,    
xmin=18.18,  
xmax=90.18,   
ymin=0,  
ymax=36,   
enlargelimits=0.01,   
xmajorgrids, 
ymajorgrids,  
colorbar sampled,  
only marks,  
view={0}{90}, % view the plot from the top
set layers=standard,  
mark layer=axis background,
]
\addplot3[scatter,  
mark=diamond*,      
point meta=\thisrow{count},  
]
table {
mean    Amplitude   count
54.18   27.54   50053
58.68   25.2    50053
64.98   15.66   50053
57.24   0.72    12112800
};

\draw[yellow!30!orange,thick](\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},4.96219281663516,0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},4.96219281663516,0)
coordinate[pos=0.8] (co);  % Cut-off-Linie
\end{axis}
\draw [latex-] (co) -- ++(3.5cm,2cm) node[right] {Cut off line};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```